# CryptProtectData - is there a CryptRemoveData

Tags: winapi, encryption

I'm reading MSDN and seeing CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData.  Is there a "CryptRemoveData" style function that I can call when my product's uninstaller runs?

I'm guessing that the [edited add words "session token"] session token data just hangs around in the HKCU hive forever if I don't remove it?

Should I instead call CryptProtectData with a very small chunk of data to clear it out.

[Edit, added this vague sentence from MSDN "Typically, only a user with logon credentials that match those of the user who encrypted the data"]

Comment: What makes you think that the data lives in the registry? Am I missing something?

Comment: `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData` encrypt/decrypt using information tied to a specific user or computer, not your software. So there is nothing for you to remove when uninstalling your software, since nothing was saved to begin with (unless you saved it yourself, in which as you are responsible for removing whatever you save)

Comment: What made me curious about the registry was this comment on the MSDN page: "However, a user with a roaming profile can decrypt the data from another computer on the network."

Comment: It is the same user, though.  Windows keeps track of the user's details for you. You are not responsible for it, so you should not be trying to clean it up yourself